# UINavigationController strange behavior after UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I am trying to restore my animation on a UINavigationController based app.
In `viewWillAppear` I do the following:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.animateButtons()
    }
```

I have also added these:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(addAnimation), name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(restorePosition), name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
```

And this is my start/restore animation:

```
 func addAnimation() {
      self.animateButtons()
    }

  func restorePosition() {
        self.restoreToOriginalPosition()
    }
```

So to explain: When controller is loaded I create my buttons `self.makeRoundQButtons` in my `viewDidLoad`. Then I animate in `viewWillAppear`.

Then when entering background I restore their original position `self.restoreToOriginalPosition()`and I animate them again once active `func addAnimation() {...}`...

Now this works fine on the "active" view. When I "drill" down on my Navigation Tree, enter background and active again, and use the "back" button to navigate to any "previous" view(s) although `viewWillAppear` is called NO animation happens. If I move forward and then back again everything works fine...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK in case someone is wondering... The problem was that I wasn't removing the `observer` on `viewDidDissapear` and all animation was done at once since all controllers where in the navigation stack!